# How do you interpret the PCA Score from data that has previously been logarithmic transformed?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, interpretation, panel-data, logarithm

I want to make financial inclusion by using PCA. Before I did PCA, I had done a logarithmic transformation on the data because my data was positive and highly skewed (I saw this from Jolliffe's book and this website: https://en.proft.me/2016/11/15/principal-component-analysis-pca-r/)

Now I want to use the PCA Score to be the independent variable in the panel data regression analysis. How to interpret the results of the parameter coefficients?

Until now I could not find a suitable reference. Please help me

Comment: If by *PCA score* you're referring to the first component, so much information is being tossed out in any subsequent regression. You can demonstrate this to yourself by building models based on the PCA score vs ones using the data inputs to the PCA. If I'm correct, the latter model would provide better results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you did PCA as opposed to factor analysis or partial least squares, but, in either case, you have to figure out what that score means. That's up to you and is based on the loadings on the variables that went into the PCA.

The fact that you took logs of the variables before doing PCA means that the interpretation of the score will be a bit different. But the interpretation of the regression coefficients is still the same: As the IV goes up by 1 point, the DV is predicted to go up by $\beta$ points, But the IV is now quite abstract. You would need to make a case for the meaning of your PC separately from the regression.

There's no guarantee that this will be optimal. PCA regression has its issues. That's why partial least squares might be useful. This was discussed here on CV in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186277/how-to-use-pca-in-regression)

Comment: Can I make an interpretation like using a transformation variable in panel data regression? This will be: "An increase in IV (financial inclusion) by 1% will cause the DV to change by 0.01 1". sorry for my bad english

Comment: No, because the PC is not in %.  You can say and increase of 1 point in the IV ...."

The PC is scored in arbirtrary units.